# Problem with user activation links

Tags: emails, registration, activation

I'm having a pretty consistent issue with the user activation links sent out in the registration emails. Having a hard time diagnosing because I can't replicate it myself, but getting several users a day contacting saying their link doesn't work. In the logs I see this:

2016/10/24 16:03:59 [warning] [application] The verification code (7TU6Z3adW6CXBmPjmgYqpJI9BeNi3cLN) given for userId: 44253 does not match the hash in the database.

I have the validationKey set in the config file and not sure if that may affect it(such as invalid characters in it), or maybe something is causing the verification code to include incorrect characters in the URL that is causing it to be truncated or read incorrectly when decoding?

The users email the end client directly, so often by the time they send me the info along, they've already manually activated them so I can't further troubleshoot.

Any ideas?

Comment: Going to be hard to verify any of this since the users are already manually activated, but that error occurs when the hash for the code that's included in the activation link doesn't match the hash for the code that was generated for the user when the email was sent out. Maybe an email client is stripping it or mangling the URL?

Comment: Is there a case where this could happen because of token expiry?

Comment: Don't think so... you'd get an "invalid/expired" token error, then.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add; we are apparently seeing this issue too. Or to be more clear: we haven't seen it ourselves, but our client keeps getting reports from their customers that Activation links are not working - giving "error messages" when clicked. We've then had the trouble mail forwarded to us, we've clicked the link, and it's been fine.

Looks like there is some mail client out there mangling the activation links. Which is bad. And we don't know of a solution.

The codes are not expired.